# Flatten data in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, group-by

I have a linq query where I need to do groupings to only select highest test date within a certain month based on testTypeId, testTakerId, subAreaId, subjectName, testDate.Value.Month, testDate.Value.Year.

The problem I am having is where the nested lists are concerned. Is there a way to flatten the data to group by testTakerId, testTypeId, subAreaId, subjectName, testDate.Value.Month, testDate.Value.Year.

The non-nested values(testTakerId, test.Value.Month, etc) work fine, but with the nested(subAreaId) values I am having trouble.

```
        var q1 = from entry in result
                 let testDate = entry.result.TestDate
                 where testDate != null
                 group entry by new { entry.testTakerId, entry.testInstance.Select(
                sr => sr.Subject.Select(c => c.subArea.Id)), entry.testInstance.Select(
                sr => sr.Subject.Select(c => c.subArea.Name)),entry.testInstance.Select(
                sr => sr.testInstance.Test.TestType.Id), testDate.Value.Month, 
                   testDate.Value.Year } into g
                 select g.Where(entry => entry.result.TestDate == g.Max(e => e.result.TestDate));
```

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), from a quick skim.

Comment: I need to get a simple property instead of a list for entries with nested properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must flatten the result set first by joining with the contained collections (`testInstance` and `Subject`) and then do the grouping:

```
var q1 = from entry in result
        from ti in entry.testInstance  // translates to a SQL join
        from su in ti.Subject          // translates to a SQL join
        let testDate = entry.result.TestDate
        where testDate != null
        group entry by new 
        {
            entry.testTakerId,
            su.subArea.Id,
            su.subArea.Name,
            ti.Test.TestType.Id,
            testDate.Value.Month, 
            testDate.Value.Year
        } 
        into g
        select g.Where(entry => entry.result.TestDate == 
                                    g.Max(e => e.result.TestDate));
```

In fluent (or method) syntax a statement like `from ti in entry.testInstance` is equivalent to `SelectMany`.

Comment: That's awesome and works great, thank you very much. Good explanation of the "sql join" translation.